# Mysterious method SmsManager.deleteStoredMessage()?

Tags: android, sms, telephony, smsmanager

I am using `contentResolver.delete(Uri uri)` for deleting sms, but occasionly found method `deleteStoredMessage(Uri uri)` in `Telephony.SmsManager` class. It was introduced in API lvl 4, not deprecated, but there are no information about this method in android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) and I also can't call it like `SmsManager.getDefault().deleteStoredMessage(uri)`.
So maybe I am missing something, but how to use it?

Comment: I'm not finding it. Do you have a source link?

Comment: @MikeM. it is at `~sdk\sources\android-21\android\telephony\SmsManager.java` here the code: http://pastebin.com/A2r65WYc

Comment: That's not API 4. That's 21. (Notice it mentions "default SMS apps", which was a concept not introduced until API 19, KitKat.) I would guess it's a new convenience method for the default SMS app, as of Lollipop.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, maybe you are right, but why there is not a single word about it in documentation and I can't use it? (Documentation says that SmsManager was introduced in API 4, and description may changed since then)

Comment: Google isn't really 100% on top of their docs and dev pages. There are pages from API 8 that still have errors. Furthermore, you wouldn't be able to use it on any device not running Lollipop. You're better off just using the Provider for now.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh, now it all clear for me, thanks!